# C# Entity Framework 6 how to insert many to many only with ids, not with the entire instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have two tables, `students` and `files` that have a many-to-many relation.

I have a service that contains an `updateStudent` method that gets the student's 
details including `fileIds` (as `List<guid>`), and update them in the database.

The method looks something like this:

```
var student = context.students.find(id)
...
update student details
...
student.files = **context.files.where(f => fileIds.contains(f.id))**
```

This line of code:

```
context.files.where(f => fileIds.contains(f.id))
```

goes to the database and returns all `File`'s data, including the content (byte array), which I don't really need, because I already have the Id's, and I only want to delete from table `studentsFiles` all the relevant student file ids and insert the new ones. But for that I don't need the file content. It is unnecessary, and can affect performance.

Do you have any alternative way to only update the many to many relation table with only the ids, without having the entire entry instance?

Thanks in advance